# php include file doesnt work

Tags: php, html

i made header.php file and i wanted to include it in index.php file ..here the code

```
<body id="home">
    <section class="container-fluid">
        <div class="content row">
            <section class="main col col-lg-8 col-sm-8">                
               <?php include"_/components/php/header.php"; ?>
            </section><!--main  -->
            <section class="sidebar col col-lg-4 col-sm-4">

            </section><!--sidebar  -->
        </div><!-- content -->
    </section><!-- container -->
```

but when display the page it doesn't work properly..here what i see in html inspector

```
<section class="main col col-lg-8 col-sm-8">                
               <!--?php include"_/components/php/header.php"; ?-->

</section>
```

Comment: sounds like you are displaying this page as a local raw html page instead of having it processed by a web server with php

Comment: Why do you use `<?php"_/folder name"; ?>` like this? Did you use this? `<?php include "folder_name/folder_name/file.php"; ?>`

Comment: Server issue, see @luciole75w comment. Also there are multiple bugs in HTML markup and also in PHP markup, for example there is no space between `include` and `"`.

Comment: thank you very much guys ..problem solved ...it seems to be local server issue

Answer (score 0):

use `include 'blabla.php';` or `include('blabla.php');` (with space or brackets) . If still not works then there must be a problem in your main php file which you are including.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

First, move you page to your local server folder so that `PHP` can be *parsed* by the server and generate HTML..then :

```
   <?php include"_/components/php/header.php"; 
           /*   ^^ add space here */ ?>
```

**Solution :**

```
 <?php include "_/components/php/header.php";  /* with space*/ ?>
```

Also, its a better practice to use `include_once` if your page contains `classes` or even a common, general purpose HTML!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this one..

```
include("header.php");
```

you don't have to require to give full path from public_html/ simple give file name in argument, you can place your header file on "public_html/header.php" location

Answer (score -1):

you can give complete path of your root directory as follows

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT]."some_folder/components/php/header.php"; ?>
```

here some _folder is optional if you have folder in root. give the name here just as component

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT]` will gives you the path of your root directory(public_html)

Comment: actually this "_" is the name of folder that contains components , css and js folders ....am i need to change this name folder???

Comment: your folder `_` is in the public html ? then try to replace `_` with `some_folder`